# Is this a valid definition of an orientable manifold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, orientation

That is, an n-dimensional manifold M is said to be *orientable* iff the tangent spaces of its points are [consistently oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)#Definition)(i.e. for any 2 distinct points p and q, the matrix $B_{pq}$ which transforms the basis vectors of $T_{p}M$ into the basis vectors of $T_{q}M$ has a positive determinant). In particular, is this equivalent to the definition of manifold orientability using homology groups?

Comment: Morally yes, but you need to be more careful to make your definition precise. It's not clear what the matrix $B_{pq}$ is. What about when $p$ and $q$ are don't lie in the same chart? What if we use a different chart?

Comment: How do you transform tangent vectors from $T_pM$ to $T_qM$? Does each tangent space have a specific list of basis vectors in order? if not, how do you determine the sign of the determinant?  (One definition that works: if there exists an atlas of charts to $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that differentials of transition maps have positive determinant. Tangent spaces are "too local".)

Comment: The notion of orientability is homological. Your definition is not precise (the word "transform" is not clear). But it can be rectified using connections.